# several connection to the same server via telnet (script js)

Tags: javascript, telnet

i'm far to be an expert in js, so be indulgeous.

i'm trying to write a script in js for opening several connection (10 here) from one server to another one via telnet protocol.

Here is my script :

```
const {
  readFileSync
} = require('fs');
//const { Client } = require('telnet-client');
const {
  Telnet
} = require('telnet-client');
const conn = (nb) => {
  const conn = new Telnet();
  conn.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`[${nb}]`, 'Client :: ready');
    conn.shell((err, stream) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
      stream.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`${nb}`, 'Stream :: close');
        conn.end();
      }).on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${nb}`, "OUTPUT: " + data);
      });
      stream.end('sleep 600\n');
    });
  }).connect({
    host: 'srvAP',
    port: 23,
    username: 'toto',
    password: 'toto'
  });
}

Array.from(Array(10)).forEach(async(x, nb) => {
  let now = Date.now();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Sleep ", nb);
    console.log(`${nb}`, "Run conn " + nb);
    conn(nb);
    console.log("Sleep end ", nb, Date.now() - now);
  }, nb * 750);
});
```

When i launch it i have some errors :

```
/exploit/tmp/SLE/poc_vega-ssh-load/node_modules/telnet-client/lib/index.js:130
                    return reject(new Error('Cannot connect'));
                                  ^

Error: Cannot connect
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/exploit/tmp/SLE/poc_vega-ssh-load/node_modules/telnet-client/lib/index.js:130:35)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:550:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Do you have an idea or for correcting this error, or for helping me writing a (more) simple script to do what i want?

Comment: is the telnet server on the other computer running? is the error immediate or does it occur a few seconds after running the script? Also, what *in principle* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes the telnet on the other computer is runing and working, the errors occurs few seconds after i launched the script, i didin't write it on my question but this is what i have on my screen before the error : 

Sleep  0
0 Run conn 0
Sleep end  0 17
Sleep  1
1 Run conn 1
Sleep end  1 753
Sleep  2
2 Run conn 2
Sleep end  2 1502
Sleep  3
3 Run conn 3
Sleep end  3 2253.

I'm trying to compare the load on server ressources for x connection with ssh et x connection with telnet. the script for ssh is already working.

Comment: see [this](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757). try running the client (lines 34 -> 49), but input your server's IP address (instead of `'127.0.0.1'`) and telnet's port - `23 `(instead of `1337`). does that give you any errors?

Comment: Ok think you, i will try as soon as possible

Comment: Yes it works. I'm going to adapt it for what i need. Thank you.